# single service with multiple exposed ports on a pod with multiple containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have gotten multiple containers to work in the same pod.

```
 kubectl apply  -f myymlpod.yml

kubectl expose pod mypod --name=myname-pod --port 8855 --type=NodePort
```

then I was able to test the "expose"

```
minikube service list
```

..

```
|-------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |          NAME           |             URL             |
|-------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|
| default     | kubernetes              | No node port                |
| default     | myname-pod              | http://192.168.99.100:30036 |
| kube-system | kube-dns                | No node port                |
| kube-system | kubernetes-dashboard    | No node port                |
|-------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|
```

Now, my myymlpod.yml has multiple containers in it.
One container has a service running on 8855, and one on 8877.

The below article ~hints~ at what I need to do .

https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/

> ### Exposing multiple containers in a Pod
>
> While this example shows how to
>   use a single container to access other containers in the pod, it’s
>   quite common for several containers in a Pod to listen on different
>   ports — all of which need to be exposed. To make this happen, you can
>   either create a single service with multiple exposed ports, or you can
>   create a single service for every poirt you’re trying to expose.

"create a single service with multiple exposed ports"

I cannot find anything on how to actually do this, expose multiple ports.

How does one expose multiple ports on a single service?

Thank you.

APPEND:

K8Containers.yml (below)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypodkindmetadataname
  labels:
    example: mylabelname

spec:

  containers:

  - name: containername-springbootfrontend
    image: mydocker.com/webfrontendspringboot:latest 
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "800Mi"
        cpu: "800m" 
      requests:
        memory: "612Mi"
        cpu: "400m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8877


  - name: containername-businessservicesspringboot
    image: mydocker.com/businessservicesspringboot:latest
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "800Mi"
        cpu: "800m" 
      requests:
        memory: "613Mi"
        cpu: "400m" 
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8855
```

---

```
kubectl apply  -f K8containers.yml
pod "mypodkindmetadataname" created

kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mypodkindmetadataname   2/2       Running   0          11s
```

---

k8services.yml (below)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: myymlservice
  labels: 
    name: myservicemetadatalabel
spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: myrestservice-servicekind-port-name
    port: 8857
    targetPort: 8855
  - name: myfrontend-servicekind-port-name
    port: 8879
    targetPort: 8877
  selector: 
    name: mypodkindmetadataname
```

........

```
kubectl apply  -f K8services.yml
service "myymlservice" created
```

........

```
 minikube service myymlservice --url
http://192.168.99.100:30784
http://192.168.99.100:31751
```

........

```
 kubectl describe service myymlservice


Name:                     myymlservice
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   name=myservicemetadatalabel
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"name":"myservicemetadatalabel"},"name":"myymlservice","namespace":"default"...
Selector:                 name=mypodkindmetadataname
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.107.75.205
Port:                     myrestservice-servicekind-port-name  8857/TCP
TargetPort:               8855/TCP
NodePort:                 myrestservice-servicekind-port-name  30784/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Port:                     myfrontend-servicekind-port-name  8879/TCP
TargetPort:               8877/TCP
NodePort:                 myfrontend-servicekind-port-name  31751/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

....

Unfortunately, it is still not working when I try to invoke the "exposed" items.

calling

http://192.168.99.100:30784/myrestmethod

does not work

and calling

http://192.168.99.100:31751

or

http://192.168.99.100:31751/index.html

does not work

Anyone see what I'm missing.

APPEND (working now)

The selector does not match on "name", it matches on label(s).

k8containers.yml (partial at the top)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypodkindmetadataname
  labels:
    myexamplelabelone: mylabelonevalue
    myexamplelabeltwo: mylabeltwovalue

spec:

  containers:

  # Main application container
  - name: containername-springbootfrontend
    image: mydocker.com/webfrontendspringboot:latest 
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "800Mi"
        cpu: "800m" 
      requests:
        memory: "612Mi"
        cpu: "400m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8877


  - name: containername-businessservicesspringboot
    image: mydocker.com/businessservicesspringboot:latest
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "800Mi"
        cpu: "800m" 
      requests:
        memory: "613Mi"
        cpu: "400m" 
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8855
```

k8services.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: myymlservice
  labels: 
    name: myservicemetadatalabel
spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: myrestservice-servicekind-port-name
    port: 8857
    targetPort: 8855
  - name: myfrontend-servicekind-port-name
    port: 8879
    targetPort: 8877
  selector: 
    myexamplelabelone: mylabelonevalue
    myexamplelabeltwo: mylabeltwovalue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create one single service with multiple ports open or service port connect pointing to container ports.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mymlservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: mymlapp
  ports:
  - name: servicename-1
    port: 4444
    targetPort: 8855
  - name: servicename-2
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8877
```

Where target ports are poting out to your container ports.

Comment: Do I "mix" this with my existing myymlpod.yml file, or does I create a new yml file for this part?  (note, I added example myymlpod.yml in my question too)

Comment: better you create new yaml file so no confusion will be there. one for service and one for pod config only

Comment: I took your advise.  And updated my question with a complete picture.  I'm still not getting calls to work (if you get a chance to look).  Thanks...

Comment: This answer is not complete, but it did get me to the eventual answer, thus my acceptance as "the answer". See my original question and the "APPEND (working now)" area for the complete answer.  Thanks Harsh for moving me along!

Comment: Thankyou for accepting it as answer actually my plan was to write the whole file for you but i am also stuck on one kubernetes issue so sorry i forget otherwise i goona append file.

Comment: Thanks.  That selector thing is tricky the first time through!  My original example (from some website) used the same string value for the name and the label, thus why it took me a while.  I hate ambiguity for values/labels on examples.  Thanks again for your help here.

Comment: :) happy to help any time