# deployment of services where one needs IP address of first service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I've created two services.

myymlservice

mysql-deployment

myymlservice needs the IP address of the load balancer of mysql-deployment (so it can create a connection string to it)

```
 minikube service list

|-------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |         NAME         |              URL               |
|-------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|
| default     | kubernetes           | No node port                   |
| default     | mysql-deployment     | http://192.168.99.100:30928    |
| default     | myymlservice         | http://192.168.99.100:32724    |
|             |                      | http://192.168.99.100:31461    |
| kube-system | kube-dns             | No node port                   |
| kube-system | kubernetes-dashboard | No node port                   |
|-------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|
```

..

```
kubectl describe service mysql-deployment
Name:                     mysql-deployment
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"mysql-deployment","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":1433,"protoc...
Selector:                 app=mysql
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.107.53.255
Port:                     <unset>  1433/TCP
TargetPort:               1433/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30928/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.7:1433
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

How (with yml) does one service (or the containers that support the service) get the IP address ?

More of my setup at the previous question:

[single service with multiple exposed ports on a pod with multiple containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935077/single-service-with-multiple-exposed-ports-on-a-pod-with-multiple-containers/55935176)

Comment: If you want to build the connection string you can use the service name instead of ip. for instance `mysql-deployment.default.svc.cluster.local`. That is because kubernetes has a "dns" [built-in](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Comment: Ok!  How about the port?  Or do I assume I know it?

Comment: Do you know what the magic kubectl query us to get the full days name?

Comment: Thanks gonazalesraul.  Future readers, the "trick' is that mysql-deployment.default.svc.cluster.local resolves the IP and the port apparently.   "default" is the namespace.  "mysql-deployment" is the service-name, and the "svc.cluster.local" is Kubernetes voodoo.  gonzalesraul, if you add an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#namespaces-and-dns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build the connection string you can use the service name instead of ip. for instance mysql-deployment.default.svc.cluster.local. That is because kubernetes has a "dns" [built-in](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and [dns resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#namespaces-and-dns)